# How to get the accurate CPU Usage per process and process Idle CPU Time

Tags: android, linux, operating-system, java-native-interface

I'hv been struggling  to get the accurate CPU Usage per process and process Idle CPU Time..
I tried " top " command proc/[pid]/stat folder but still trying my luck..

TOP command gives CPU usage for all the processes running in fg(foreground) and bg(background)
but it is not as accurate i feel.. because it shows %CPU 0, even if the process is running in the background.. Any other way? please help

Comment: Dumpsys cpuinfo works absolutely fine on 2.2 and 2.3.6 but when i tried on 4.0, it gives me an error message for output like "Permission Denial: can't dump Battery service from pid..." Also, when the application is launched there is an item in the log tagged with "PackageManager" statingNot granting permission android.permissionDUMP to package.... (protectionLevel = 3 ...)"

Comment: DUMP permission will not work after Android 4.0 or 4.1, you have to use your app as a root user or put it into /system/app/yourapp.apk.

Comment: @VISHAL /system/app/yourapp.apk. requires either a rooted ROM or a rooted device which is not what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do it myself..
I am using

1. proc/[pid]/stat -> for per process CPU Usage 14th and 15th parameter
2. proc/stat       -> for All processes CPU consumption at the same time

Comment: Answer with more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31274572/2872712

Comment: `/proc/stat` is no longer accessible as of Android O ([see here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140047))

Answer (score 1):

You can get CPU usage with:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        // -m 10, how many entries you want, -d 1, delay by how much, -n 1,
        // number of iterations
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -m 15 -d 1 -n 1");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        int i = 0;
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            Log.e("Output "   i, line);
            list.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            i  ;
        }

        p.waitFor();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Got update",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Caught", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Top command sums up the results. The results are not in the decimal values.