# Calculating CPU Usage of a Process in Android

Tags: android, linux, cpu-usage

I am trying to calculate the CPU usage of a process in Android as follows, however i am not sure if its right due to the output produced.

To convert from jiffie to seconds: jiffie / hertz

**1st step:** get the uptime using the 1st parameter of `/proc/uptime` file.

**2nd step:** get the number of clock ticks per second from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`.

**3rd step:** get the totaltime spent by the process `(utime(14) +stime(15))` parameters from `/proc/[pid]/stat`

**4th step:** get the starttime(22) of the process from `/proc/[pid]/stat`
the value is expressed in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)) after Linux 2.6.

**5th step:** get the total elapsed time of the process since it started `(uptime - (starttime / hertz)` (since uptime is in seconds and starttime is in clock ticks).

**6th step:** get the CPU usage percentage `((totaltime / hertz) / elapsedTime) * 100`.

The output after the calculation is something like 5.702244483458246E-6 which is approximately equal to ~0.000005702244483

**EDIT**

Output

Step 1: 226.06 1211.19

Step 2: 1000000

Step 3: 9347 (example.com) S 3573 3573 0 0 -1 1077952832 8971 0 1 0 38 32 0 0 20 0 25 0 13137 983830528 14330 4294967295 1 1 0 0 0 0 4612 0 38136 4294967295 0 0 17 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Reference: [How do I get the total CPU usage of an application from /proc/pid/stat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat)

Comment: The utime/stime values give you an approximation of the CPU usage of the process (you will need to sum them up over all threads) over the course of its lifetime. Are you trying to get the *recent* percent CPU usage, e.g. what the `top` command reports?

Comment: Actually i am trying to get the CPU usage of an application from when it is started until i purposely kill it. What do you mean by sum them up over "all threads" ? do you mean over all CPU's on the device? cpu0-->cpu7 (in case the device has 8 cpu's)?

Comment: @T-D If you list out the specific values you get from the respective files which you use in your calculations, we may be able to track down any errors in your arithmetic and process.

Comment: @VilhelmGray Alright i edited my question.

Comment: @T-D What is the value returned by `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation of error

I suspect that you used the value in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` as your `hertz` value. This is incorrect since that file gives you the CPU hardware clock frequency, but you must use the Linux kernel clock frequency as your `hertz` value.

The CPU hardware clock and Linux kernel clock are different. The Linux kernel -- which Android runs -- has its own timer (clock) which it updates at a certain frequency; the frequency at which this timer updates is the kernel hertz (`HZ`) value.

For [historical reasons](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec2), the clock tick values listed in Linux proc and sys files are scaled from the kernel `HZ` frequency to a common frequency via the Linux kernel `USER_HZ` constant. It is this `USER_HZ` constant which we must use as the `hertz` value in our calculations.

## Acquisition of data

- **uptime**: `226.06` seconds
- **utime**: `38` clock ticks
- **stime**: `32` clock ticks
- **starttime**: `13137` clock ticks
- **Hertz**: `100` (Linux kernel `USER_HZ` constant)

  - This is under the assumption of an [unmodified Android system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28293555/1806289).

## Computation

`total_time = utime + stime = 38 + 32 = 70`

`seconds = uptime - (starttime / Hertz) = 226.06 - (13137 / 100) = 94.69`

`cpu_usage = 100 * ((total_time / Hertz) / seconds) = 100 * ((70 / 100) / 94.69) = 0.7392...`

## Solution

The total CPU usage of your process is about **0.739%**. If this seems small, remember that your process shares the CPU with all the other processes on the system: the majority of normal processes are idle for most of their life, so any one process will typically average a low total CPU usage.

Comment: How does frequency scaling figure into all this?  Are the cpu and process times (e.g. utime, stime) normalized to Fmax?  If they are not, wouldn't a process running at the lowest frequency and a process running for the same duration at the max frequency show the same CPU utilization?

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that on most Android devices the value will be 100, on some devices it could be a different value. That is because this value depends on the CPU's architecture. **ARM** CPUs would have **100** for the USER_HZ constant value but **x86** CPUs would have **1000** as you can see [here](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec2).